# How should I measure the "fit" between two sequences?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

This question is for a machine learning application, which, surprisingly, is not stock price prediction. I apologize for being overbroad, but any ideas or even help framing the question would be greatly appreciated.

My application is generating sequences of numbers that I later want to compare against a sequence of actual measurements. For a set of generated sequences, I want a measure that allows me to rank them as they compare to the actual.

I have these intended uses for this data:

1) to select the "best" generated sequence from a set, to present to the client

2) to provide feedback to the machine learning algorithm

3) to communicate the quality of the algorithm's choices to the client

For example:

actual: [1000, 1200, 700, 900, 2100, 2500, 2700]

generated: [1000, 1500, 600, 700, 1200, 1100, 700]

generated: [1000, 2000, 2100, 3300, 4200, 6000, 6100]

generated: [1000, 1100, 1000, 900, 1100, 1200, 1400]

- I can calculate the percent error between elements of the two sequences, and average that over the length of the sequence. (But that number can range widely -- it can get really big if the generated sequence is way off.)
- I can also calculate what percent of the generated sequences fall inside some threshold for error percentage (e.g. error margin of +/- 30%). That gives me an overall measure of the quality of generated sequences.
- I can average the variance between the elements in the two sequences, as the square root of the sum of the squares of differences between the two sequences. (That value can range widely, too.)
- I have a "quality" measure that sums the logs of the absolute differences, and raises some constant to that value; i.e. 0.99 ^ z where z = the sum of log(abs(a - g)) for each a=actual and g=generated value. This is nice because it falls off exponentially as the difference increases, and is guaranteed to be between 0 and 1, which makes it easier to feed back into the machine learning algorithm.
- In searching before I asked this, I saw another answer that brought up the Minkowski distance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426398/how-to-determine-distance-between-two-sequences-e-g-1-2-3-and-1-1-3

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance

If anyone has some good ideas, or can even help me to frame the question better, it would be a huge help.

Comment: Do all the numbers have equal importance? Are the sets all of length 7?

Comment: Yes, the numbers all have equal importance. The length of the generated sequences is always the same for each batch. The lengths may vary between batches. However you can treat them as always having the same length as a simplification.

Comment: In real life, the lengths vary between 50 and 1000. (And the generated sequences always match their associated sequence of measurements.) But I'm OK with treating it as 7 for this discussion.

Comment: Gotcha. So say you find a way to rank the quality of the generated sets, does your algorithm already know how to improve itself based on that?

Comment: That's right. The goal is to improve the quality over time based on the feedback.

Comment: Well it seems to me that the simplest thing to do that will definitely work is to just compute $D = \frac{|\vec{x}_{\text{act}} - \vec{x}_{\text{gen}}|}{|\vec{x}_{\text{gen}}||\vec{x}_{\text{act}}|}$ (aka, your third idea, but divided by the product of the magntidues of the two vectors.) By the triangle inequality$$
\bigg|\frac{1}{|\vec{x}_{\text{act}}|} - \frac{1}{|\vec{x}_{\text{gen}}|}\bigg|\leq D\leq \frac{1}{|\vec{x}_{\text{act}}|} + \frac{1}{|\vec{x}_{\text{gen}}|}
$$
so you wouldn't have to worry about it varying too much.

Comment: That's great -- I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Also that triangle inequality makes it nice; I can scale it to 0..1, which the machine learning algorithm likes, with $d = \frac{D - lower}{upper - lower}$. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your program :)